# Minimality of the positive part of a self-adjoint operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, positive-semidefinite

Given a bounded self-adjoint operator $T$ on a Hilbert space $H$, the *Jordan decomposition* asserts that there exists a unique pair of bounded positive operators $(T_+,T_-)$ such that
$$
  T = T_+ - T_-, \quad \text{and}\quad
  T_+T_-=0.
  $$
For that reason $T_+$ and $T_-$ are often called the *positive* and *negative* part of $T$, respectlvely.
In particular $T\leq T_+$.

**Question**.  Is $T_+$ the smallest positive operator bigger than $T$?  In other words, if $S$ is a bounded positive operator on $H$, such that $T\leq S$, does it follow that $T_+\leq S$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: **The following is true in the case that $T_+$ is invertible.**

We have that $T_+-T_-\leq S$. Note that since $T_-T_+=T_+T_-=0$, we have that $T_-p(T_+)=p(T_+)T_-=0$ for any polynomial $p(z)$ **with constant term $0$**. Now since $T_+$ is invertible, $0\not\in\sigma(T_+)$, so the spectrum of $T_+$ is a closed set contained in an interval $[\varepsilon, M]$, where $0<\varepsilon<M<\infty$. The functions $f_n(t)=t^{1/n}$ defined on $\sigma(T_+)$ are continuous and each one can be uniformly approximated by polynomials with constant term $0$, so we have that $f_n(T_+)T_-=T_-f_n(T_+)=0$ for all $n$. But note that since $f_n\to1$ uniformly on $\sigma(T_+)$ we have that $f_n(T_+)\to\text{id}_H$ in norm. This actually proves that $T_-=0$, and the result follows trivially.

In the case that $T_+$ is not invertible, we cannot say anything: As OP commented, consider for example $T=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&-1}$, then $T_+=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}$. Consider the matrix $S=\pmatrix{9&-6\\-6&4}$, then we have that
$$S=\pmatrix{3&-2\\0&0}^*\cdot\pmatrix{3&-2\\0&0}\geq0$$
and we have that
$$S-T=\pmatrix{8&-6\\-6&5}\geq0$$
since the eigenvalues of $S-T$ are $\frac{13\pm 3\sqrt{17}}{2}$. On the other hand, we have that

$$S-T_+=\pmatrix{8&-6\\-6&4}$$
and the eigenvalues of $S-T_+$ are $6\pm 2\sqrt{10}$, one of which is negative.

Comment: I think your statement that $T_+^{1/n}\to\text{Id}_H$, as $n\to\infty$, does not hold.  For example, if $T=\pmatrix {1 & 0 \cr 0 & -1}$, then $$T_+=\pmatrix {1 & 0 \cr 0 & 0} = T_+^{1/n}.$$

Comment: @Black you are right, it was a stupid mistake of mine. I have edited my post.

Comment: Two points: when $T_+$ is invertible then $T_-=0$, so $T$ is already positive and my conjecture becomes tautological.  Secondly, your $S$ is not positive so it doesn't give a counter example.

Comment: your first point is exactly what I am saying. About your second point, I didn't notice you wanted $S$ to be positive. I am editing again.

Comment: @Black I think we are done here

Comment: Bingo!  Now you've got it.  Thanks very much!  Just a little comment: to check that a $2\times2$ self adjoint matrix is positive it is enough to check that the trace and determinant are positive since these are the sum and the product of the eigenvalues!